# How to add dynamic column to my table?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have one form in my app,i am creating textview and edittext programmatically,as per user requirement,user can create number of textviews and edittext,on click of add button,now issue is i am not able to store all the values of dynamically created textviews and edittexts to my table...the values nameofevent,date,time,duration is storing properly in my table..following is image of my form..can any one tell what is the mistake?

[image]

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button addnewdata;
    private Button submit;
    private EditText edtnmofevent;
    private EditText edtdtofevent;
    private EditText edttmofevent;
    private EditText edtdurationofevent;
     private LinearLayout lnr;
        private TextView valueTV;
        private EditText edtvalues;

        int totalFields = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          addnewdata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addnewdata);
            submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
            edtnmofevent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtnameofevent);
            edtdtofevent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtdateofevent);
            edttmofevent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttimeofevent);
            edtdurationofevent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtdurationofevent); 

            addnewdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MainActivity.this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
                    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                            .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                               lnr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addnewlinear);
                                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                                lp.setMargins(25, 0, 0, 0);
                                                valueTV = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                                // valueTV.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                                valueTV.setText(userInput.getText());
                                                valueTV.setLayoutParams(lp);
                                                valueTV.setTextSize(18);
                                                valueTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2d6cae"));
                                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                                lp1.setMargins(25, 0, 25, 0);
                                                lp1.height = 50;
                                                edtvalues = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                                                edtvalues.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rect_edt);
                                                edtvalues.setLayoutParams(lp1);
                                                lnr.addView(valueTV);
                                                lnr.addView(edtvalues);
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
            });

            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String edcity=edtnmofevent.getText().toString();
                    String dtofevent = edtdtofevent.getText().toString();
                    String timeofevent = edttmofevent.getText().toString();
                    String duration = edtdurationofevent.getText().toString();

                    queries q=new queries(MainActivity.this);
                  //  q.insert(edcity, dtofevent, timeofevent, duration);


                        String dlabl=valueTV.getText().toString();
                        String dedt=edtvalues.getText().toString();
                        q.insertevnt(dlabl,dedt);
                        System.out.print("values of textand edit"+valueTV.getText().toString());

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    }


}
```

queries.java

```
public class queries {
    SQLiteDatabase sd;
    public queries(Context c)
    {
        db_handler dh=new db_handler(c);
        sd=dh.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    public void insert(String city,String dateofevent,String timeofevent,String durationofevent)
    {
        String query="insert into tbl_spin(city,dateofevent,timeofevent,durationofevent)values('"+city+"','"+dateofevent+"','"+timeofevent+"','"+durationofevent+"')";
        sd.execSQL(query);
    }
    public Cursor select()
    {
     //  String query="select tbl_spin.city from tbl_spin INNER JOIN tbl_event ON tbl_spin.id=tbl_event.id";
      String query="select * from tbl_event";
        //String query="select city from tbl_spin CROSS JOIN tbl_event";
        Cursor c=   sd.rawQuery(query, null);
        return c;
    }

   public void insertevnt(String txtofevent,String edtofevent)
    {
        String querys="insert into tbl_event(txtofevent,edtofevent)values('"+txtofevent+"','"+edtofevent+"')";
        sd.execSQL(querys);
    }

    /*public Cursor selectevent()
    {
        String querys="select * from tbl_event";
        Cursor c=   sd.rawQuery(querys, null);
        return c;
    }*/

}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"


    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="IT ADD$"
            android:id="@+id/itaddestxt"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="UP"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itaddestxt"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/addnewlinear"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ADD NEW EVENT"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/txtaddnewevent"
                android:textColor="#73b5fa"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtaddnewevent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/bluelines"
                />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name of Event:*"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bluelines"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#2d6cae"
                android:id="@+id/txtnameofevent"
                />


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/edtnameofevent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtnameofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date of Event:*"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtnameofevent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#2d6cae"
                android:id="@+id/txtdateofevent"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtdateofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/reledtdate"
                >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/edtdateofevent"

                />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edtdateofevent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/calndrdat"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time of Event:*"
                android:layout_below="@+id/reledtdate"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#2d6cae"
                android:id="@+id/txttimeofevent"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txttimeofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/reledttime"
                >
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/edttimeofevent"

                />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edttimeofevent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/timepickrs"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Duration of Event:*"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edttimeofevent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#2d6cae"
                android:id="@+id/txtdurationofevent"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/edtdurationofevent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtdurationofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtdurationofevent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/addnewdata"
                android:text="Add"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/btnsubmit"
                />

            </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

db_handler

```
public class db_handler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public db_handler(Context context
    ) {
        super(context, "databs.db", null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table tbl_spin(id integer primary key autoincrement,city text,dateofevent text,timeofevent text,durationofevent text)");
        db.execSQL("create table tbl_event(id integer primary key autoincrement,txtofevent text,edtofevent text)");


       // db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE COMPANY(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,NAME CHAR(50) NOT NULL,AGE CHAR(50) NOT NULL,ADDRESS CHAR(50) NOT NULL,SALARY CHAR(50) NOT NULL);");
      //  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,DEPT CHAR(50) NOT NULL,EMP_ID INT NOT NULL);");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Comment: r u trying to add views or store its value to table?

Comment: What exactly views or its value?

Comment: give your xml file also where you r trying to add views.

Comment: is there any exception?

Comment: if i add two times textview and edittext..it gives only last inserted items

Comment: like if i add in first generated editetext 100 and again i click on add button and add 101 to edittext..it gives 101 instead of 100 and 101

Comment: @chandil03 any idea bro?

Comment: You code seems fine. Try debugging it. Try to find what exactly happening there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89638/discussion-between-aditya-and-chandil03).

Comment: You should not add columns dynamically, because you would have to check how many columns there are every time you pull information. besides creating an object to hold the information isn't impossible but I don't think thats a good idea.
Have you thought about noSQL db and JSON?

Comment: the thing which i am trying to do is not possible?